# implement member? on simply scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm following SICP and Computer Science 61A using Dr. racket and simply-scheme as my editor, there is a function `member?` that check if the first argument is an element of the second that is not implemented in simply-scheme so I'm trying to implement my own, I have this recursive procedure:

```
(define vocals '(a e i o u))

(define (member? x (y vocals))
  (cond ((equal? x (first y)) #t)
    ((member? x (bf y)))
    ))
```

It works for vocals but i don't know how to add a stop case for when x is not a vocal

Comment: You need a base case when `y` is an empty list.

Comment: SICP does not use `member?`, but you should read (and do the exercises) of section 2.3.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `(y vocals)` parameter and `(bf y)`? You should probably review the fundamentals again.